# Problem with evaluation of functions with arguments other than $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If I have a function of the type
$$m(x+3)=5x+8.$$
Calculate $m(5)$ which is equal to 18 I have no problem, but the problem occurs when I am asked for

$$m(x^2+1/x) = x^2 +2x+1 , m(5)=?$$

o

$$m(x^3+x+5) =4x^3-2x-18 ,m(-2)=$$

or this

$$t(x^2+3x-2/(x^2+1)) = x^3-3x-2 , t(k)=$$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah how does that help with the other problems?

Comment: solve, solve and solve.

Comment: The one with $m(x^2+1/x)$ isn't even a proper function since there are multiple values for a single $m(x)$, I'd assume others aren't as well.

Comment: the function $t$ is missing an important bracket somewhere

Comment: Did you make these up yourself, BeTDa? Because your first and third examples don't make sense. For such definitions to be valid, the expression inside the parentheses on the left-hand side has to be an invertible function.

Comment: If you have any with quadratic or cubic arguments, I don't care, I don't know what the solution procedure is when the argument is not linear.

Do they have to fulfill some specific condition?
I have looked for theory of this type of problems but this is specific I can't find it.

Comment: Let me see if I can help you. Your actual problem is simply that you want to find $x$ from some $f(x)$ in $m\left(f(x)\right)$ for which $f(x)$ is $t$ so set $f(x)=t$ and then try to write $x$ in terms of $t$. For instance, in your first example, you want $x$ for which $f(x)=x+3$ is $t=5$ so set $x+3=5$. If there are multiple values of $x$ then $m(f(x))$ better be same for all of those values of $x$ otherwise, it won't be a function anymore. This method may not always work (Why?) but it's *one* of the best hopes that mankind has at the novice level. The other best option is to cry.

Comment: When the transformation is linear, there is no problem, I get complicated arguments with $x^n , with n>=2.$